# I encountered Signature is found in scriptCode exception when trying to make a BTC transfer

Tags: bitcoin-core, transactions, raw-transaction, bitcoinj

When I transferred a 0.001 BTC from `miBEA6o6nZcaLZebR1dsDv4AMHRwJk1mbi` to `miV1sbmLM9fptRfWD5o8hs5L6ucUeJzmp5`, the following error occurred: `mandatory-script-verify-flag-failed (Signature is found in scriptCode) (code 16)`.

This is my broadcast data:

```
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`
```

The test method I performed: https://github.com/lingting/VirtualCurrency/blob/0.3.1/src/test/java/live/lingting/virtual/currency/omni/Transfer.java#L130

Transfer operation, signed code: https://github.com/lingting/VirtualCurrency/blob/0.3.1/src/main/java/live/lingting/virtual/currency/service/impl/BtcOmniServiceImpl.java#L248

The signature is at: https://github.com/lingting/VirtualCurrency/blob/0.3.1/src/main/java/live/lingting/virtual/currency/service/impl/BtcOmniServiceImpl.java#L335

Signature code:

```
        List<TransactionInput> inputs = tx.getInputs();
     
    for (int i = 0; i < inputs.size(); i++) {
        Script script = ScriptBuilder.createOutputScript(fromAddress);
        TransactionInput txIn = tx.getInput(i);

        Sha256Hash hash = tx.hashForSignature(i, script, SigHash.ALL, false);
        ECKey.ECDSASignature ecdsaSignature = key.sign(hash);
        TransactionSignature txSignature = new TransactionSignature(ecdsaSignature, SigHash.ALL, false);
        if (ScriptPattern.isP2PK(script)) {
            txIn.setScriptSig(ScriptBuilder.createInputScript(txSignature));
        }
        else if (ScriptPattern.isP2SH(script)) {
            txIn.setScriptSig(ScriptBuilder.createP2SHMultiSigInputScript(ListUtil.toList(txSignature), script));
        }
        else if (ScriptPattern.isP2PKH(script)) {
            txIn.setScriptSig(ScriptBuilder.createInputScript(txSignature, key));
        }
        else if (ScriptPattern.isP2WPKH(script)) {
            Script scriptCode = ScriptBuilder.createP2PKHOutputScript(key);
            TransactionSignature signature = tx.calculateWitnessSignature(i, key, scriptCode, txIn.getValue(),
                    SigHash.ALL, false);
            txIn.setScriptSig(ScriptBuilder.createEmpty());
            txIn.setWitness(TransactionWitness.redeemP2WPKH(signature, key));
        }
        else {
            throw new ScriptException(ScriptError.SCRIPT_ERR_UNKNOWN_ERROR,
                    "Unable to sign this scriptPubKey: " + script);
        }
    }
```

I would like to ask what is wrong with my code. In my submission this time https://github.com/lingting/VirtualCurrency/commit/0ea9b090d6fe2e4821afc10b5725436d56f2909d#diff-25a6634263c1b1f6fc4697a04e2b9904ea4b042a89f59dc848a. I can still submit the code normally. , I also tested it at the time, and there are several transfers in the test address I generated to prove it, but why is it not possible now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The referenced outputs are P2PK
- `createOutputScript(fromAddress)` implies P2PKH
- P2PKH scriptSig doesn't match with P2PK pubkeyscript

Resources used to write this three-line answer:

- Compile Core
- Use 30 GB bandwidth to download the blockchain
- Two-three hours of time

but I'm happy to help more if this isn't enough.

Comment: Thank you very much, the transfer was successful!